# how to get windows forms to run in parallels on windows 11

Tags: c#, macos, parallels

Hello I am new to c# and I am trying to combine my app with windows forms.
I am aware that windows forms doesn't work on Mac so I am using Windows 11 on parallels virtual machine to code.
I tried using the solution  explorer to reference the projects to each other but I keep on getting this error:

```
Project `/Users/John/Documents/test/forms/forms.csproj` cannot be added due to incompatible targeted frameworks between the two projects. Review the project you are trying to add and verify that is compatible with the following targets:
    - net7.0
```

These are my two csproj files:

**forms.csproj.user file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Form1.cs">
            <SubType>Form</SubType>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**app.csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I should change the two files?

Comment: That is not what a Winforms project looks like.  Do pick the project template to get started, instead of typing it yourself,  it avoids a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @HansPassant I did that and it worked thanks a lot